# How to effectively save database password in desktop application?

Tags: database, desktop-application, database-security

I'm making desktop application (lets call it app) which uses database (mysql).
More app's users share one database user.
Example : John and Mike app users connect to DB as "dbuser", etc.

The problem is : **How do I effectively save passwords for DB users?** (app users's pwds are stored in DB).

Possible solutions I found : 
1. in the code - this is actually pretty stupid :D
2. in the text INI file - easy to read!
3. encrypted in extern file - good, but need access to app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (app users's pwds are stored in DB).

Encrypt stored passwords using [SHA1/SHA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA_hash_functions) algorithm. This is the most used technique. 
I'm not a .NET developer but I'm pretty sure that they provide the function somewhere.

When user logs in, encrypt again the given password and compare it to the stored one. If they are equal, let the user log in.

Comment: You just overwrite them. See for example any dynamic website: if you want to change your password, you must provide the old one and then write the new one. The system encrypts the given old one password, checks if this is equal to the password actually stored, then encrypts the new password and overwrites the password stored.

Comment: I see. Okay I give you example.
I decide to change location (IP) of DB server which my APP uses. I should do it thru app GUI or just "manually" edit some extern file from app loads data?

Comment: If you're using a very nice and easy configuration file, I think that you could let the user edit that file manually. 

If App is aimed to very unexperienced users, it should be better to have this job done by App's GUI, through a Preferences window

Comment: I agree that database IP should be only somewhere in file
Also db users, but encrypted (in extern file)

Comment: give also a try to SQLite (http://sqlite.org). It is a very easy and tiny database system in form of a library. I guess it is also packaged with .NET framework. You could store any setting preference in any table, as well as encrypted passwords. The database is a single file within your project directory

Comment: Sounds good, but It is already quite ... ehm ... big database (I use MySQL). The point is, it needs to be online, but I'll also look to SQLite as you suggest.
OH and I dont use .NET, but Java ;)

Comment: Hem, I don't know why I was completely convinced that you were using .net :) 
Nobody will blame you if you use sqlite for internal details such as application configuration, user name etc, and keep using Mysql for the rest. Sqlite is not an external database server, everything stays inside your application. Also db4o (http://db4o.com) is a very nice tool for Java that does the same job as sqlite, but is an object-oriented database

Comment: well I need external DB server, but SQLite sounds perferct for saving inernal data. But isnt it actually quite luxoury? :) When I text file is enough? :D

Comment: This depends on the quantity and the quality of the information you want to be stored in. A text file is a good idea when you have few information, but you must pay attention for things such as updating fields or appending new lines. A tiny database automatically nadles concerns such these, obviously

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in the INI file in the encrypted format. That is best way IMHO. I stores connection string in the App.config of .NET application in the encrypted format.

EDIT:

To edit connection string, I use another configuration value in AppSettings of App.Config file CSEncryption="Y|N|R"

if it is Y, connection string is encrypted, decrypt and use it.

if it is N, connection string is not encrypted, use it directly.

if it is R, connection string is not encrypted, encrypt it and update connection string and set CSEncryption to 'Y' in App.Config.

Comment: and how do you then edit encrypted file? when etc. migrating on another DB hostname?

Comment: on top of that you should always use a secure channel (SSL) to communicate to the server, else with a little effort anyone can sniff some packets and find out the password

Comment: +1 to rsilva. If the database is accessible over a network, it is a good idea to use SSL to communicate with it

Comment: And if you are going to go through all of that trouble, ensure the database user has the least amount of privileges to get the job done.

Comment: Brettski - thanx, I handled that :) I'll give a try with SSL also.

Comment: Please try look upper to example I have to bodom_lx